# Is it possible to obtain a public share link with the original name of the file?

Tags: ubuntu-one, file-sharing

I don't want to have public link for downloading and sharing which obfuscates the file name and file type like for example: http://ubuntuone.com/3y88jj4O7noyEngvCnxG88 (sample link, won't work).

Instead, is it possible to obtain a link which shows the file name and file extension? 
Example: http://ubuntuone.com/name-of-my-file.mp3

So, how do I find the option that lets me share public links with the original name of the file?

Comment: I am not the OP. However, I just *hate* it when people downvote (either a question or an answer) w/o explaining the reason. What value does this have? How can the OP improve the question? Obviously, he is a fresh member here - what welcome message does he get if the 1st response is an unexplained downvote???!?!?!

Comment: @ysap Please check the revisions. It wasn't a good question at first and was closed. I did initially drop a comment about the question's state and then took the liberty to edit and improve it and got it reopened.

Comment: Reason of my question is this: imagine you have colleague / classmate / partner... and you need to share e.g. 5 links (of files on U1), but with actual system your partner has no clue what file is what. That’s the reason for real names of files, instead of letters and numbers in file links

Answer (score 4):

While Ubuntu One itself doesn't provide this service, there is a 3rd party site, called u1.to which can.